# How can I distinguish and incorporate my skill systems with each other?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems, rpg

I'm trying to write a [litrpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LitRPG) where skills has 3 types of systems.

They are:

1. Skill Tier.       [Skill tier goes from tier 1 to tier 4]
2. Skill Evolution.  [Skill evolution happens when a character levels up every 10th level]
3. Skill Sub-Levels. [Skill sub-levels depend on the skill]

So for example a fireball skill when it experiences evolution it will be:

- The skill fire ball will become greater fire ball.
- It will increase its quality and quantity.
- Increase the users manipulation of the skill.
- Increase in power.

While skill sub-levels will be like this:

- The fire ball aoe damage will increase by 50%.
- Fire balls will seek your targets.
- The fire balls are tripled in number.

But I'm kinda lost about skill tier. It's kinda like skill evolution. As skill ascends to higher tier the stronger the skill is. But I think skill evolution already does this. So, guys I hope you can help me with this. I want to refine this idea to be more distinguished from each other.

Comment: This is a question about designing game mechanics, not about designing the world the game will be played in.  Assuming by "litrpg" you are talking about a tabletop RPG (TTRPG) then this topic could be asked about on Roleplaying SE.  However, even there you need to be asking a more specific question by providing criteria for what will be considered a "good" answer.

Comment: Questions about game mechanics aren't permitted on this site.

Comment: In a lot of litrpg worlds how worlds work is determined by game mechanics, so I don't think they should be completely off the board.

Comment: I was torn off, but I eventually chose to close (off-topic) : There's no world context at all, which means all answers can't work on the world-part. It's as if your main intentions are to offer a fun arcadey game, one which doesn't have any story. You should answer some of these questions to ask beyond game-design : how does people throw and learn magic in this world : years working on magic breathing, studying in libraries, attuning to spirits and artifacts...? What's the meaning of "tiers" and "Evolution" in your game world, rather than from the point of view of outsiders of said world?

Comment: I've been reading a lot of LitRPG recently, and the development of intuitive gaming mechanics is how they do world building. That said, this group seems to revolve around identifying what plot points could be sold by a decent author as plausible. This involves an understanding of physics, sociology, and world history. The ability to build that into a viable gaming mechanic is a distinctly different skill set; one that this group isn't focused on accumulating. I vote to close for "not this community" reasons, but, @user84527, would like to see where it goes.

Comment: @RobertRapplean May I ask which place would be best to ask this type of questions?

Answer (score 3):

## Add unique effects.

You have power, you have control. Make skill tier about how weird the fire is.

So a tier 1 fireball just burns the enemy. It does damage, and they die.

A tier 2 fireball, eldritch flames, has a sticky quality. It will do damage over time to whatever it hits that can't be extinguished by water and is harder to heal with mundane healing.

A tier 3 fireball, fire of the legion of flames Krazalotot, will do all of the above and cause anyone who dies of flames to generate a second smaller fireball, allowing you to hit massive areas.

A tier 4 fireball, Flames of Hestia, will do all of the above, and empower any allies it hits with increased fire damage and resistance and not do them any damage.

Answer (score 2):

**Skip the tiers.**

You have 2 different ways to level up already and a vision for how each works.  You do not mention your vision for how to "tier up" and I suspect it overlaps with evolution.

3 categories of leveling up gets to be a lot for participants to follow.  Keep it simple.

Consider keeping the term "tier" which is a good term and using that instead of "evolution" which is a lot more vague.  You can have as many tiers as you like if you have lots of ideas for a given power.  Possibly not all powers have the same number of tiers.  Some powers might go really high.